# Are Du Val singularities smoothable?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, birational-geometry, singularity-theory

I am interested in when a Du Val surface singularity is smoothable. By Du Val singularity, I mean (the germ of a) isolated double point surface singularity admitting a resolution by blowups of isolated double points over the original. By smoothable, I mean when does there exist a flat family containing the singularity as one of the fibers, and a smooth germ as another fiber.

Any solution/reference would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Du Val singularities are indeed smoothable and, in fact, more is true: they are *of class* $T$, namely, they are quotient singularities admitting a $1$-parameter $\mathbb{Q}$-Gorenstein smoothing.

See Definition 1.1 and Proposition 1.2 in the paper

M. Manetti: [On the moduli space of diffeomorphic algebraic surfaces](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s002220000101), *Invent. Math*. **143**, No. 1, 29-76 (2001). [ZBL1060.14520](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1060.14520),

where they are called *rational double points*.

Answer (score 13):

Du Val singularities are hypersurface singularities, hence they can be smoothed --- just replace the defining equation $F(x,y,z) = 0$ by the equation $F(x,y,z) = \epsilon$.